# Activity indicator is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

In my app data comes from web service and I have implemented code to show activity indicator. 
I fetch data from web service in viewWillAppear().

The issue is that the indicator is shown  only once when first time viewWillAppear() is called and after that whenever viewWillAppear() method is called indicator is not showing.

My code is as follows :-

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Initializaing  views for Acticity Indicators
   loadingview = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];    
    Tickview=    [[tickview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];   
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
        if ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN))
        {                 
           [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Check Your Internet Connection. Internet   Connection is not active" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }       
}

- (void)startTheBackgroundJob
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}

-(void)loading
{
     //
     //some database operations here..
     //


    //after that showing the activity indicator
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadAnimates:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];



    //retriving data from web service..   
    [self retrieveData];


    //than removing loadingview
     [loadingview removeFromSuperview];
     [loadingview setHidden:YES];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tickshow:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(tickhide:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2]; 

}

 - (void) threadAnimates:(id)data
{
[self.view addSubview:self.loadingview];

[loadingview setHidden:NO];

}

-(void)tickshow:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:Tickview];
    [loadingview setHidden:NO];
}

-(void)tickhide:(id)sender
{
    [Tickview removeFromSuperview];
    [Tickview setHidden:YES];
}
```

And when i put break point for dubegging , the indicator is again showing, but when remove the break point , the indicator is not showing.

I have imported seperate files for loadingview and tickview both in .h file and in project.

I have tried a lot but could not get the solution.

Please help me.

Comment: Take the activity indicator in viewwillappear, you might be taking in viewdidload.

Comment: where is the start method for "loading activity indicator"

Comment: just write [yourActivityIndicator startAnimating];

Comment: thanks all for reply. But the code for starting indicator is in Loading.m file for which i have made object as loadingview

Comment: why dont you try [indicator startAnimating] and [indicator stopAnimating] methods instead of adding and removing views.

Comment: you mean you take ActivityIndicator with loadingView name in Loading.m file??

Comment: @ParasJoshi- ya exactly. starting and stoping is done in that Loading.m file. I am just adding and removing that loadingview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Initializaing  views for Acticity Indicators
   loadingview = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];    
    Tickview=    [[tickview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];   
    [loadingview startAnimating];
   [self.view addSubview:loadingview];

   [self.view bringSubviewToFront: loadingview];
}
```

**Edited :**

also try bellow code for just add Activity Indicator in view

```
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinningWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 11.0, 25.0, 25.0)];
        [spinningWheel startAnimating];
        spinningWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        [self.view addSubview:spinningWheel];
        [spinningWheel release];
```

i hope this help you..

:)

Comment: thanks for reply. But it gives me "SIGABRT". And i have seperate files Loading.h and Loading.m in which there is activity indicator used. I am just adding that loadingview in my view

Comment: then just add loadingview.indicator try this

Comment: thanks again. i have tried your code but still it is not showing

Comment: but mate where you add loadingView?? first addSubview with loadingView and What is TickView??

Comment: sorry. i have updated my code. I am adding loadingview in threadAnimates method and Tickview is anotherview showing "images downloaded"

Answer (score 0):

Write only `[self.ActiveIndicatorName startAnimating];` statement in `ViewWillAppear` method.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [self.ActiveIndicatorName startAnimating];

        Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
        if ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN))
        {                 
           [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Check Your Internet Connection. Internet   Connection is not active" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }       
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: whenever your ViewWillAppear method call [self.ActiveIndicatorName startAnimating]; is start your Active Indicator. if u not understand then google is best way for understanding  this statement

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `ViewWillAppear` method like this ....

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//Initializaing  views for Acticity Indicators
loadingview = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];    
Tickview=    [[tickview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];  
[Tickview startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you are loading the request  , you should start loading the indicator [myActivityIndicator startAnimating]; and stop it using delegate. If the activity indicator is created in nib file dont forget to set it hidden on stopping (hides when stopped). Hope this helps out.